# Testnet blockchain inconsistencies - geth diverged from original blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets

I'm using `go-ethereum instance: Geth/v1.5.9-unstable-fa999861/linux/go1.7.4`. I cloned it from github (commit: `fa99986143fe3dec08cdffcff9185e3700719edd`).

On Feb, 6th I synchronized with testnet via `./build/bin/geth —-testnet —-fast —-cache 1024 -—rpc -—ws`. After successful sync, `eth.syncing` started to return `false`. I created a [new account](https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0x33abfc219c5930fa46d7331f0d2feae25abccdbd) via web3 API calls. I used the [faucet](http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001) twice to fund the account.

The transactions/balances were not visible in [testnet.etherscan.io](https://testnet.etherscan.io), though after some time, the balance of the account (visible via `eth.getBalance(eth.account[0])`) increased from 0 to 2 ethers.

On Feb, 7th I ran `./build/bin/geth -—testnet --cache 1024 —-rpc —-ws` to start `geth`. Via another console (`geth attach`) I created a [second account](https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0xe4866e47ae609b62c3d01af23a74c83bc814987f). I used the faucet again and funded both accounts with 1 ether each. Now, the transactions showed up in [testnet.etherscan.io](https://testnet.etherscan.io), but I could not see the balance increase via `eth.getBalance`. I even made a [transaction](https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0xfb6bf16a7be2b5f2093a7a3330ce794b7181b4cb3c3a7e5527f9137ce642442b) between the accounts, which is reflected both in the blockchain explorer and also via `eth.getBalance` calls.

The weird thing is that, compared to etherscan, I'm lagging behind in terms of number of blocks. I'm connected to 1 peer only, plus I see:

```
I0207 23:37:00.459143 eth/downloader/downloader.go:723] Peer 2335d4125a0c5f6f [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: potential rewrite attack: #394279 [00000000…] <= #394279 limit

I0207 23:40:04.500520 eth/downloader/downloader.go:723] Peer 995c53d7b78fcf82 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: potential rewrite attack: #394279 [00000000…] <= #394279 limit

[...]

I0208 00:58:21.335954 eth/downloader/downloader.go:623] Peer 16ab7523de2c0967 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: head header set (item 0) broke chain ordering: requested 484431, got 484446
```

in the logs. While checking example blocks, I have the feeling that I diverged from the original blockchain:

```
eth.getBlock(484634).hash
“0xc8016bca08924e45d5aa4a2f58ef824e8c1a4238be22ce4eaa16411c102f10cb"

vs.

https://testnet.etherscan.io/block/484634
0x79a96fcaddfd584e3f5b1b4057a1af53418234bc662a4297599487af01e34277
```

In summary:

```
+=================================+================================+=====================================+
|          Time, Action           |              geth              |              etherscan              |
+=================================+================================+=====================================+
| Feb, 6th - Testnet fastsync     | -                              | -                                   |
+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Feb, 6th - Account creation     | -                              | -                                   |
+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Feb, 6th - 2x faucet            | 2 ether                        | 0 ether                             |
+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Feb, 7th - 2nd account creation | [2 ether, 0 ether]             | [0 ether, 0 ether]                  |
+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Feb, 7th - 2x faucet            | [2 ether, 0 ether]             | [1 ether, 1 ether]                  |
+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Feb, 7th - tx                   | [1.99957999, 0.00000001 ether] | [0.99957999 ether, 1.00000001 ether |
+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Where do the inconsistencies come from? Why is my transaction visible locally via geth, though I'm not synchronized with the correct blockchain anymore?